# Permission based on nodes/section of site

Tags: users

Is it possible to alter permissions based on content types/individual nodes or sections of the site? If so, how?

Comment: Are you looking to to this in code, or through the UI with contributed modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving roles different permissions for different *content types* is possible even with core drupal straight out of the box!  Check it out: just create a new content type, and go to edit the permissions of any of your current roles (**/admin/people/permissions**).

Under the '**Node**' section of the permissions, you'll see you can select which content types each role can create, edit and delete.  The create/edit/delete permissions under this section simply repeat for each of the content types on your site (so you have to visit this section and adjust permissions as needed each time you add a new content type).

Now, if you want different roles to have distinct permissions based on both content types and where on the website those content types appear, you'll have to add the functionality of additional modules to your site.  One good one is the [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) module.  That modules allows your site to be organized in groups (or sections) with users having distinct permissions depending on which group/section they are members of.  I cannot possible go into all the details of using that module in this answer, however, a good place to start if you feel you need this functionality, would be the module's own documentation pages: http://drupal.org/node/1114858

Good luck!